# tensorflow results are weird. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

It has two inputs and one output.

Input: [Temperature, Humidity]

Output: [wattage]

I learned as follows
Even after 5 million rotations, it does not work properly.

Did I choose the wrong option?

```js
var input_data = [
[-2.4,2.7,9,14.2,17.1,22.8,281,25.9,22.6,15.6,8.2,0.6],
[58,56,63,54,68,73,71,74,71,70,68,62]
];
 
var power_data = [239,224,189,189,179,192,243,317,224,190,189,202];
 
var reason_data = tf.tensor2d(input_data);
var result_data = tf.tensor(power_data);
 
var X = tf.input({ shape: [2] });
var Y = tf.layers.dense({ units: 1 }).apply(X);
var model = tf.model({ inputs: X, outputs: Y });
var compileParam = { optimizer: tf.train.adam(), loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError }

model.compile(compileParam);
 
var fitParam = {
    epochs: 500000,
    callbacks: {
        onEpochEnd: function (epoch, logs) {
            console.log('epoch', epoch, logs, "RMSE --> ", Math.sqrt(logs.loss));
        }
    }
}  
model.fit(reason_data, result_data, fitParam).then(function (result) {
 
    var final_result = model.predict(reason_data);    
    final_result.print();
    model.save('file:///path/');
});
```

The following is the result for 5 million times.

[image]

It should be the same as power_data , but it failed.

What should I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is rarely one simple reason to point to when a model doesn't perform the way you would expect, here are some options to consider:

1. **You don't have enough data points**. Twelve is not nearly sufficient to get an accurate result.
2. **You need to normalize the data of the input tensors**. Given that your two features [temperature and humidity] have different ranges, they need to be normalized to give them equal opportunity to influence the output. The following is a normalization function you could start with:

```js
function normalize(tensor, min, max) {
  const result = tf.tidy(function() {
    // Find the minimum value contained in the Tensor.
    const MIN_VALUES = min || tf.min(tensor, 0);

    // Find the maximum value contained in the Tensor.
    const MAX_VALUES = max || tf.max(tensor, 0);

    // Now calculate subtract the MIN_VALUE from every value in the Tensor
    // And store the results in a new Tensor.
    const TENSOR_SUBTRACT_MIN_VALUE = tf.sub(tensor, MIN_VALUES);

    // Calculate the range size of possible values.
    const RANGE_SIZE = tf.sub(MAX_VALUES, MIN_VALUES);

    // Calculate the adjusted values divided by the range size as a new Tensor.
    const NORMALIZED_VALUES = tf.div(TENSOR_SUBTRACT_MIN_VALUE, RANGE_SIZE);
    
    // Return the important tensors.
    return {NORMALIZED_VALUES, MIN_VALUES, MAX_VALUES};
  });
  return result;
}
```

3. **You should try a different optimizer**. Adam might be the best choice, but for a linear regression problem such as this, you should also consider Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD).

Check out [this sample code](https://glitch.com/%7Enon-linear-data-multi-layer-perceptron) for an example that uses normalization and sgd. I ran your data points through the code (after making the changes to the tensors so they fit your data), and I was able to reduce the loss to less than 40. There is room for improvement, but that's where adding more data points comes in.